# Migrating Django Project with reversion Library to Golang (Gin) - Implementation Query

Tags: python, django, go, go-gin

We are presently in the midst of migrating a Python (Django) project to Golang (Gin). Within our application, we utilize the reversion library. How to implement this functionality during migration to Golang?

```
@reversion.register()
class DocumentRecommendationMedia(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey("Document.Document", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=settings.DOCUMENT_RECOMMENDATION_PATH)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "document_recommendation_media"

@reversion.register(fields=("recommendation", "date", "media_files"))
class DocumentRecommendation(ArchivableModel):
    document = models.ForeignKey("Document.Document", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recommendation = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    media_files = models.ManyToManyField(DocumentRecommendationMedia, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "document_recommendation"
```

How to implement reversion in Golang?

Comment: I think this is too large for you to get a good answer here. In the docs there is a description of how django-revision works, which may be a start for how you may want to work that into your new implementation. https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8.1/how-it-works.html
> Whenever you save changes to a model, it is serialized using the Django serialization framework into a JSON string. This is saved to the database as a reversion.models.Version model. Each Version model is linked to a model instance using a GenericForeignKey.

Comment: Are there equivalents to Django-reversion in Golang? Is a custom solution needed here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrating a Django Project using the reversion library to Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77741921/migrating-a-django-project-using-the-reversion-library-to-golang)